# cannot filter group by displayName like '?fitler=displayname eq APPLICATION/myRole' in SCIM 2.0 API(WSO2 IS 5.7.0)

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I've created two roles in WSO2 IS v5.7.0. The 1st one '_login' is in 'Primary' domain. The 2nd one 'Manager' is in 'Application' domain. I try to search the group by display name like this. The first query is OK, but the 2nd query returns empty response. Could you help?

1st query: **curl -v -k --user admin:xxx 'https://localhost:9444/scim2/Groups?filter=displayName+eq+_login'**

2nd query:**curl -v -k --user admin:xxx 'https://localhost:9444/scim2/Groups?filter=displayName+eq+Application/Manager'**

Answer (score 0):

Roles starting from Application/ are special kind of Internal role dedicated to represent service providers.

EX: Suppose you create a service provider with name xxx. There will be a automatically created role Application/xxx. Service provider xxx will be visible to only users belong to  Application/xxx role.

It's a good practice to keep roles starting Application/ away from general user management stuff.

Comment: My user who makes the request belongs to the target `Application/xxx` role but the API still returns no results. What else is needed?